# Robots.txt: ALLOW Google Fonts

Tags: css, robots.txt, googlebot

I've been testing my website with Google Webmaster Tools and when I tried to "fetch it as Googlebot" I got a "Partial" status and a note that three EXTERNAL css files, namely 3 Google fonts, had been blocked for some reason by robots. txt.

Now, here's my file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemapindex.xml
```

Is there something wrong with it that might be preventing access to said files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If robots.txt is blocking *external* CSS files, then it will be the robots.txt for the server hosting those files, not the one for your main hostname.

I don't know why you would worry about Googlebot being unable to read your stylesheets though.

Comment: Next to that, why would it need to read your text in a special font? As long as it's read and indexed.

Comment: All right, thanks Quentin, I figured as much myself. As for the reason I worry, it's because Google has a tendency to lower your SEO rank if it can't properly render your site and missing stylesheets fall under that category.